# XPath: How to select the first given parent of a node?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

My XML:

```
<root>
  <child>
     <childOfChild>
        <anotherLostChild>
           <currentSelectedNode>
              SOME TEXT
           </currentSelectedNode>
        </anotherLostChild>
     </childOfChild>
  </child>
</root>
```

I selected the node **currentSelectedNode** using:

```
xpath.SelectSingleNode("//currentSelectedNode")
```

But How can I back to select the first **chilfOfChild** parent node (considering that the context is **currentSelectedNode**?

```
xpath.SelectSingleNode("//currentSelectedNode")...???
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question is really confusingly written but it sounds like you'd want the [ancestor axis](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp), something like:

```
//currentSelectedNode/ancestor::childOfChild[1]
```

(pure xpath solution)

Answer (score 3):

```
xpath.SelectSingleNode("//currentSelectedNode/../..")
```

this will select the parent's parent

Answer (score 0):

In Linq-To-XML you would need only to use the Ancestor method:

To get the immediate ancestor:

```
xElement.Ancestor();
```

To specify which ancestor:

```
xElement.Ancestor("NameOfTheAncestorNode");
```

Comment: The Ancestor() method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Using `XElement xElem`, you can use `xElem.Parent` to get the immediate parent.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.parent(v=vs.110).aspx

To select specific ancestor nodes, you can use

```
xElem.Ancestors("currentSelectedNode");
```

to get all ancestors with that specific node name.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348268(v=vs.110).aspx